# How come these 2 variables are always in their initialized state in the useEffect() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to use `setCuteName` to change the `cuteName` variable based on the average(avg) of the `scores` array.
However, inside the `useEffect` method, `avg` and `scores` are always the values they were initialized in at the top. Even after the average is set, it still prints out 0 in the console log. But I know it's not 0 because in the JSX it shows the actual average.

Right now, `cuteName` is set to the same name every time since `avg` is always 0. How do I fix or get around this? I'm currently researching more about hooks and how they work since this is my first time working with hooks, but still haven't found a way around this.

JSX that uses the avg state below

```
<strong>Average Score:</strong> {avg} points
```

```
  const [avg, setAvg] = useState(0);
  const [scores, setScores] = useState(null);
  let [cuteName, setCuteName] = useState('');


  useEffect(() => {
    usersCollection
      .doc(user.uid)
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.data().scores) {
          let arr = doc.data().scores.reverse();
          setScores(arr);
          setLast(
            month[arr[0].createdAt.toDate().getMonth()] +
              ' ' +
              arr[0].createdAt.toDate().getDate() +
              ', ' +
              arr[0].createdAt.toDate().getFullYear()
          );
          var sum = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + arr[i].score;
          }
          
          //AVG set here
          setAvg((sum / arr.length).toFixed(2));
         
          //NOTE: avg is always 0 and scores array is undefined
          setCuteName(nicknames.forEach(function (score, index) {
            if(avg>= score.bottom){
              cuteName = nicknames[index].name;
            }
          }))
            
          console.log("testing : " + cuteName);

        } else {
          setScores(undefined);
          setLast('N/A');
        }

        setName(doc.data().firstName + ' ' + doc.data().lastName);
        setSchool(doc.data().school);
      
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: You'll need to use temporary variables inside useEffect, that's how state works - https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-doesnt-react-update-thisstate-synchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand the overall objective of the app, and this answer isn't meant to really get you to your ultimate goal. I would, however, like to point out the numerous issues you have that will hopefully point you in the right direction.

1. Most state changes are asyncornous and as such, when you call `setAvg((sum / arr.length).toFixed(2));`, you shouldn't expect the `avg` variable to change right below it.
2. `setAvg((sum / arr.length).toFixed(2));` sets the `avg` value to a string and thus doing this `if(avg>= score.bottom){` will result in unexpected behavior.
3. This sets the state to `undefined` as `forEach` does not return anything:

```
        setCuteName(nicknames.forEach(function (score, index) {
            if(avg>= score.bottom){
              cuteName = nicknames[index].name;
            }
          }))
```

On top of that, `cuteName = nicknames[index].name;` mutates the state directly, which is a no no in React.

I hope some of this stuff is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the tips :) How can I make it so that I wait for the setAvg line to finish before moving on to the next lines of code?

Comment: @cris But I am not sure you even need to wait. Why not just assign that average to a regular variable like so: `const const_avg = sum / arr.length;`, then set the state `setAvg((sum / arr.length).toFixed(2));` and then check the average using the `const_avg` variable? `if(const_avg>= score.bottom){`

Comment: True! That's so simple, I can't believe I didn't even think about that. Goes to show I still need to improve lol. Thanks again mate!

Comment: @cris Yep. Just keep in mind that this `setCuteName(nicknames.forEach(function (score, index) {...` is a pretty insurmountable obstacle and will need to be refactored in some way. You should probably just take that `forEach` out of the state setter function.

Comment: I did refactor it after reading your initial post. 
```
 nicknames.forEach(function (nickname, index) {
            if(const_avg >= nickname.bottom){
              setCuteName(nicknames[index].name);
            }
          });
```

This is what I ended up doing